# Can't connect to Openshift mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, openshift

I'm trying to connect to my Openshift MYSQL database on a database called OTA

Whenever i try to connect i get the error -

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin881Rhs7'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

While i'm using a password

```
private String ConnectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OTA?"
    + "user=admin881Rhs7&password=9JDlLn1r****";


public ResultSet ExecuteSQL(String query) throws Exception {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // setup the connection with the DB.
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString);

        // statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        // resultSet gets the result of the SQL query
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        // writeResultSet(resultSet);
```

I can't seem to connect to the remote database using this connection, but I can logon onto the database using PHPMyAdmin

Note: I've tried changing "localhost" in my connection String to the IP of the server on database and doesn't work either

I've also granted my user previlages and still says (using password: NO )

Any help is appreciated , please note that this is on open-shift servers.

Comment: Try `String ConnectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OTA"` and `DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString, "yourUsername", "yourPassword")`.

Comment: Nope, Still the same error  java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin881Rhs7'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Well, then try to find a reason for `using password: NO`. It seems that your login omits the password for some reason.

Comment: Yeah i'm wondering why is that happening as well :'(

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this app on OPENSHIFT you need to replace the localhost by MySQL server IP, you can get the IP using this command

```
rhc port-forward -a <mysql-gear-name>
```

and then used the same IP DriverManager

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X:3306/OTA", "admin881Rhs7", "9JDlLn1r****")
```